# Why can't resize button in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode

My Xcode is 7.1. And I tried to resize in the program as follow.

```
CGRect buttonFrame = self.button.frame;
buttonFrame.size.width = 100;
buttonFrame.size.height = 60;
self.button.frame = buttonFrame;
```

I have two constraints only and set to `"Bottom space to : Bottom layout guide" and "Align Centre X to : SuperView"`. Then I set to AutoResize subviews to UNCHECKED. Why I can resize in the program?

Answer (score 0):

setting the frame manually and mixing autolayouts dont work well together, its better to set a width and height constraint then have an outlet to them so you can change those constraints to set the new width and height

Comment: Yeah i did same as suggested. Put two more constraints for width and height. Constraints are working so that the button size is same as constraints. But using outlet, I tried to change the size in the program, still doesn't work.

Comment: you may need to call `[buttonSuperView layoutIfNeeded]` where buttonSuperView is the view that contains the button for it to take effect (especially if doing animations)

Comment: also check if you arent getting a bunch of errors in the console showing autolayouts breaking because of the resizing of the view

Comment: I don't know what is the problem, create button programatically is more manageable. I created button programatically. Thanks